# Droning/rubbing sound from left brake pad after recent change

Tags: tires

I recently changed my wife's brake pads on her toyota corolla, 09 or something. We used some universal cermaic plates, by the way. It was my first time changing brake pads and it took a bit but I did it successfully, atleast I think. I took it out for a spin to make sure I wasn't letting my wife go off in a death trap made out of my own incompetence, and it braked fine. I got up to 60 or so a few times and did a long brake, a shorter brake, and a short stop. Each time the brakes were fine, and the really bad shaking in the steering wheel that would happen before during a brake had stopped.

HOWEVER, there is a very concerning droning sound coming from the left wheel when braking, and sometimes at lower speeds without a brake. It is especially worse when lightly braking while making a left hand turn. Is this something to be concerned about? I also noticed there's a slight metallic ringing to it too, barely perceivable. I've read that this could be something like dust between the brake pad and rotor or the rotor not being "accustomed" to the shape of the newer brake pad? Should I crank it back up and take a look at them or just drive it around a bit more and see if the noise lessens?

Comment: Did you replace the rotors (discs) and pads?

Comment: Can you share a link to those “universal ceramic plates”?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a wheel bearing that is worn.  Safely the wheel of the ground slightly and see if you can get the wheel to wobble on its axle by gripping the tire and twist it from side to side at different locations around the wheel.  There should be no noticeable movement on its axle.

While the wheel is raised, rotate it by hand and listen to where any rumbling sound comes from.  If it is the bearing, it will come from the centre of the wheel.

Comment: Not wobbling on its axle, it's on there tight. Did not replace the rotors, just the pads, also the brakepads in question are "Carquest" brand.